Unique Filtered Data
I have a sheet of Data (Unifrog interactions (without Benchmark 8)) that on another sheet (Benchmark 4) I have filtered in Cell A2 to make sure I only get data in Column G that has "4." in it. All is working fine but I would like to then maybe use the =Unique function to only get records based on unique entries in Column D of the Benchmark 4 tab.
Filter Test

Can you manually enter & showcase us what your ideal expected output would be like for the given test data?!

@rockinfreakshow I have added a tab and manually deleted the duplicates as per what I’d want it to look like

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.


You may try:
=let(Λ,'Unifrog interactions (without Benchmark 8)'!A:G, Σ,filter(Λ,find("4.",index(Λ,,7))),
     x,sort(Σ),sort(sortn(x,9^9,2,index(x,,4),1)))



INCREDIBLE. Side note, where on earth would I go to learn this..?
